# Telerik RadEditor - Setting the ImageManager.ViewPath to a directory outside of my current site

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radeditor

I am new to the editor and couldn't find anything when searching. My application is located like so:

http://localhost/CMS/default.aspx

but I want the ViewPath to pick up the directory:

http://localhost/Images

If I try and use Page.ResolveUrl with a relative Url to that location, I get an error saying "Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory."

Is there another way I should be doing this or is it not possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you do it like `~/Images/YourImage.jpg` ?

Comment: Because ~/Images would be http://localhost/CMS/Images, not http://localhost/Images

Comment: Yes. That's right. But the parent domain is CMS. right?

Comment: Yes. The domain for this site would be: `http://localhost/CMS/default.aspx` but I need to be able to set it up one more level.

Comment: You coulud be able to validate the correct image path under CMS only. I think.

Comment: The editor I am currently using allows me to point it to any directory so it isn't a limitation in ASP.NET but is something to do with the editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is, you can create a virtual folder under CMS folder with the name Images which will point to the the same folder as `localHost/images`

So both `localhost/images` and `localhost/cms/images` will point to the same physical location.

refer this http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/editor/uploading-images-and-files-to-a-shared-drive.aspx